# Making a sentence more concise and formal?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I want to express this following meaning:

> I tutored several students for xxx course and the students I tutored got better scores than average, specifically 17% better than the class average.

I wanted to put this on my resume and it should start with a past tense verb, the format should be like:

> Provided tutoring for a second year course about xxx

Comment: If you list your accomplishments, don't use the pronoun. Just start with the verb. *Tutored students whose scores were 17% higher than the class average.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally try to be as concise as possible on a resume, while still getting the point across. Something like below:

> Students I tutored in xxx achieved 17% above class average.

Answer (score -1):

> April 2019 - Tutoring for a second year course about xxx (Tutored students
>   get 17% better than the class average).

Or simply:

> April 2019 -  Tutoring for a second year course about xxx.